# Почему нельзя сохранять файлы напрямую в папку public (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, symlinks

Вопрос про файловую систему Lumen/Laravel:

В документации есть блок описывающий следующее:
Диск public предназначен для общего доступа к файлам. По умолчанию диск public использует драйвер local и хранит файлы в storage/app/public. Чтобы сделать их доступными через веб, вам надо создать символьную ссылку из public/storage на storage/app/public.

Из этого возникает вопрос: зачем нужно делать ссылку на другую папку? Почему нельзя сразу сохранять файлы в папку public? 
Было предположение, что это не позволит получить доступ напрямую ко всем файлам, лежащим в public'ке, но это оказлось не так.

Answer (score 3):

В [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk) же есть ответ на ваш вопрос.

`This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.`

То бишь нужно это для разделения публичных файлов проекта (css, js, index.php, robots.txt, etc.) и файлов конкретного экземпляра проекта (например загруженные через админку картинки и т.п.).

Это более корректно с точки зрения организации проекта и не создаст проблем при автоматическом деплое.

НО никто не мешает вам сохранять в public директорию напрямую, достаточно в `config/filesystems.php` поменять

```
'root' => storage_path('app/public')
```

на

```
'root' => public_path('storage'),
```

у диска `public`.